# Get HTML Form Field Names

Tags: php

I have a HTML form that is dynamically generated. I can manage coding in Php + cURL to automatically login to any website. However, in this case, the form field names are changing every time the form is loaded.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the form field names once the form is loaded. After that I can make use of the Form Field Names to further manipulate.

You need not restrict yourself to Php but it is preferable.

Comment: I know you can get elements by id with javascript but then it does need to have a id.

Comment: @Mythje, All elements may not have ID tag. Also he may not necessarily know the IDs of the elements.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean by 'Form Field Names'? Is that the name attribute for each input tags in your form?

Comment: @Ajay That's why i said that it does need to have a id ;)
katsou11's solution is better in all ways anyway

Answer (score 3):

I would load the page in a [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) object, then use [getElementByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) with 'form' to get every form nodes from the page. you can then loop throught each form fields names.

Here is some code for you to start, it would help if you know the form's name attribute or something. Because getElementsByTagName will return every form tags on the page.

```
// Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure 
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 

// Load the html's contents into DOM 
@$xml->loadHTML($html);
// get each form in a DOMNodeList
$forms = $xml->getElementsByTagName('form');

foreach ($forms as $form) {
    // if you know the form name attribute, you could check it here before continuing...
    // with $form->getAttribute('name'), and the continue with next iteration if not the right one
    // loop throught each input tags in the form
    $inputs = $form->getElementsByTagName('input');
    foreach ($inputs as $input) {
        // get input name attribute and value and ...
        $inputName = $input->getAttribute('name');
        $inputValue = $input->getAttribute('value');
        ...
    }
}
```

An other way is to use a Xpath expression, like this:

```
// Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure 
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 

// Load the html's contents into DOM 
@$xml->loadHTML($html);

$oXpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

// will return a DOMNodeList of every input from every forms
$inputs = $oXpath->query("//form//input");

// again , knowing the name attribute of the form is better, you could use:
//$oXpath->query("//form[@name='form_name']//input");
// you would be sure to have the correct inputs in your list

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    //loop through inputs ...
}
```

#### note

It would greatly help if the form you're trying to get the data from is identifiable, by an attribute (name, id), or by being surrounded by the same type of parent node (i.e. the form is always in a div with a fixed id,...), look for such a pattern in your sources and I might be able to give you a proper Code/Xpath expression.

Comment: @Awais Qarni Thanks. @OP I could throw some starter code if you want to try this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you mean something like this?

DOMNodeList DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName ( string $name )

where let's say $name="form"

I read from the manuals that it returns DOMNodeList I however wonder how to get the values of field names from this array. A little insight would be helpful Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appreciate you trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM as mentioned by katsuo11. Here is the sample JS code which may help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayFormValues()
{
    var str = '';
    var elem = document.getElementById('frmMain').elements;
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
    {
        str += "<b>Type:</b>" + elem[i].type + "&nbsp&nbsp";
        str += "<b>Name:</b>" + elem[i].name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        str += "<b>Value:</b><i>" + elem[i].value + "</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        str += "<BR>";
    } 
    document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```