# retrieve "name='field_name' "

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get HTML Form Field Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855833/get-html-form-field-names)

I have a very big form and I'm looking for a quick way to retrieve the name of all html form field names, like:

```
<textarea class="txt" type="textarea" name="txt_fahe" rows="2" cols="20">
<select class="dropd" name="sel_mob4" size="1">
...
```

Any hints on how to make the expression? it should support " and '

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
<(?:textarea|select|input)\b[^>]*\sname\s*=\s*(['"])(.*?)\1
```

Comment: I get this error: ERROR: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: Actually I'm using this: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: as i just need the names and it's not part of any script

Comment: @Cornwell - if you would work with regex for a while, you knew  that syntax is `/pattern/`, so in this case you need to enter `/<(?:textarea|select|input)\b[^>]*\sname\s*=\s*(['"])(.*?)\1/`. Check results of `array[2]`...

Answer (score 1):

Try using JavaScript : `$('form').serialize()`